# Android Speech to Text - offline constant recognition

Tags: android

Doing some research I have found some different speech to text API's for Android.

[Pocket Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/)

[Android Native API](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/)

I have the following requirements:

1. Must be able to support offline speech recognition (I'm not sure
   if the Android API can do this)
2. Must be able to detect and
   respond immediately to every word said.  I would rather this than
   detecting an entire sentence.  I could split the returned sentence
   into and array though and get each word.
3. The detection needs to
   be processing in the backgound (no popups or anything as the Android
   API seems to do)

Can someone recommend an API that is capable of my requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pocketsphinx meets all your requirements. What you call the "Android Native API" is basically a set of interface definitions and it does not contain the notion of offline/online.

You can also implement these interfaces using Pocketsphinx, since it supports things like partial results, confidence scores, n-best results etc. This way the implementation becomes available to any Android app. Maybe somebody has done it already, but I'm not aware of it.